# Syntax error when referencing form data in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to mail form data in an HTML form when the user submits the form. The syntax error comes when putting quotes around `fullName` in the body of the email. If there are no quotes, it doesn't show an error. I'm new to PHP and am not really sure how to reference an HTML form from within PHP, when I've declared that a set of code is HTML. Here is my code:

NOTE: I'm using Dreamweaver to code this and sometimes the syntax correction is incorrect, but I want to make sure before I go ignoring it and code my entire document.

```php
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'smtpusername';
$mail->Password = 'smtppassword';

$mail->From="mailer@example.com";
$mail->FromName="My site's mailer";
$mail->Sender="mailer@example.com";

$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test 1";

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "
<h1>Graphics Request</h1>

Name: $_POST['fullName']<br />
";
$mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
}
else
{
   echo "Letter is sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: Enclose in `{}` inside the double-quoted string as in `{$_POST['fullName']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is, in fact, a syntax error in PHP.  Because you're inside a double-quoted string, you can (and must) just write `$_POST[fullname]` there.

This is an example of the designers of PHP trying to *help* you.  Like they did when they broke the boolean operators and the behavior of `continue` inside a `switch`.

Comment: Or use something like {$variable}

Comment: @Napolux: Or that.  I tend to go for the concise option.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! Looks like I'm going to have an interesting time learning PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I put all post results in variables, you should get into this habit, it makes thing like the above work . Just my .02 cents

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as:

```
$mail->Body = "
<h1>Graphics Request</h1>

Name: {$_POST['fullName']}<br />
";
```